# Pentaho Kettle Java 11 Roadmap

Tags: java, java-11, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Currently Pentaho Kettle (v.9.1) officially only support Java 8. This is a problem for us, since we are maintaining a plugin that needs Java 11 because of a essential library that needs Java 11. Does anyone have details on the roadmap for the migration to Java 11. I could only find some older information that Java 11 is on the roadmap, but not when it will be available for Kettle.

Our current solution is to use Java 11. You can get Spoon running when removing the JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS from the bat/sh file. But this is not the best solution since the application is not fully compatible and we are experiencing more and more problems.

Also alternative ideas or solutions are welcome.

Comment: any solutions to this? I still get an error when trying to run PDI 9.1 with Java 11, november 2020

Answer (score 1):

As of May 20, the [README.md of the Pentaho Kettle repository](https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle) explicitly mentions Java 11, so it seems as if that is now officially supported.

Comment: I can verify that it is working now.
It also worked for me to use JDK 17 now. But I would suggest to use JDK version 11 like recomented in the official docomentation.